# How do you change a button's color only when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css

Is this what I use? It doesn't seem to be working.

```
<style>
    button:hover {
    background-color : red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: There's [nothing wrong with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/v5owv8xg/)

Comment: Is there other html/css in play since that should work.

Comment: If you're targeting all buttons the dom... This is correct.

Comment: your code is just fine. are you sure you're using a `button` element?

Comment: Use your browser to inspect this. Either your style is not being applied or something else is taking priority.

Comment: Maybe you have another css stylesheet that overwrites your rule. Orm aybe you have a input[type=submit] and not a button. Check in inspector, for button/input[type=submit] and see if anything overwrites this inline style

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you also want to target `<input type="submit">` and other buttons.

You can do that with multiple selectors:

```css
button:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```css
button:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<input type="button" value="Button" />
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/toothbrush7777777/zqgypwzb/1/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Its all fine with your code but may be it can be possible for override, if it override you can add the new class to the button and selecting the button in css using the class name of the button.

HTML:

```
    <button class="test">Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
    button.test:hover{
    background-color: red;
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zqgypwzb/5/)

Comment: This is generally bad practice. If something is overriding your css, you should make sure the order of your css is correct instead of using `!important`.

Comment: No, you're still using `!important`. That's the bad part.